# Merge and Left Join keeps duplicating line items in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, match, unique

I am struggling with this issue that I am unable to fix! I have to data-frames ("Master" and " "Hours"). The 'Master' df has many columns but the ones in particular are as follows below:

**Master**

```
StoreNumber ... MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN 
     1           0   0   0   0   0   0   0
     2           0   0   0   0   0   0   0
     3           0   0   0   0   0   0   0
     ...
```

NB: The Master df has many columns in between StoreNumber as the days of the week and holds a lot of data (about 3000 stores)

**Hours**

```
BranchNumber   Day   TimeDiff
     1         MON   7.50
     1         TUE   6.00
     1         WED   8.50
     1         THU   2.00
     1         FRI   1.00
     1         SAT   2.50
     3         MON   7.50
     3         TUE   6.00
     3         WED   8.50
     3         THU   2.00
     3         FRI   1.00
     3         SAT   2.50
     3         SUN   5.00
    ...
```

So the idea is that I am trying to match the 'Hours' BrandNumber with the  'Master' StoreNumber. Once there is a match then it matched the Day column from the 'Hours' table with the Days of the week in the 'Masters' Table...It will do this for each row and then populate days of the week with the corresponding value in 'TimeDiff' column...if the store and branch number has no match (Like StoreNumber 2) then it should skip that row and move onto the next. Another condition, like BranchNumber '1' there is no data for SUNDAY so in the 'Master' table the SUNDAY cell should be left as 0...this should work for any day of the week.

The output should be the 'Master' Table but complete with all the days of the week data from the 'Hours' Table. In this example, it should look like:

```
    StoreNumber ... MON    TUE   WED   THU   FRI   SAT   SUN 
         1          7.50  6.00  8.50  2.00  1.00  2.50    0
         2           0      0     0     0     0     0     0
         3          7.50  6.00  8.50  2.00  1.00  2.50  5.00
     ...
```

The code I have tried is semi-working but I am not sure if its the correct approach. The biggest problem I am getting is that its duplicating the rows expect from the first row. For instance, the output looks more like this.

```
StoreNumber
    1
    2
    2
    3
    3
    4
    4
    5
    5 
    5
```

all are duplicating and some tripling and every 87 columns are identical...however the days of the week of the duplicated row are all 0's.

```
 merged <- Master %>% select(-c("MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT","SUN")) %>%
 left_join(
 Hours %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Day, values_from = TimeDiff),
 by = c('StoreNumber' = 'BranchNumber'))

 merged <- merged %>% replace(is.na(.),0)
```

Sorry for the long question, this issue has been bugging me a while so any help/advice will be grateful

Comment: I would suggest using `pivot_longer` on `Master` before the join, not `pivot_wider` on `Hours`. Then you can join on both the store/branch number and the day of the week. After the join, you can use `pivot_wider` to get the result in to the shape you want.

Comment: @GregorThomas I am sorry to ask but would you be able to show a little bit of code so I can understand where to go from what you've said? I am very new to R so am still learning

Comment: Sorry - I don't have time right now. I'll try to get to it tomorrow in case no one else comes along sooner.

Comment: Thank you @GregorThomas much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the `Master` table has many columns and only the columns `MON` to `SUN` need to be updated.

Here are two approaches which uses `data.table`'s ability to *update in a join*. Only the relevant columns are modified by reference, i.e., without copying the whole data object. It avoids to reshape (or pivot) the `Master` table forth and back.

### Variant 1

```
library(data.table)
days <- names(Master)[which(names(Master) == "MON") + (0:6)]
setDT(Master)[, (days) := lapply(.SD, as.double), .SDcols = days]
for (d in days) {
  Master[Hours, on =.(StoreNumber = BranchNumber), (d) := TimeDiff[d == Day], by = .EACHI]
}
Master[]
```

> ```
>    StoreNumber OtherCol MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN
> 1:           1        a 7.5   6 8.5   2   1 2.5   0
> 2:           2        b 0.0   0 0.0   0   0 0.0   0
> 3:           3        c 7.5   6 8.5   2   1 2.5   5
> ```

#### Explanation

- `days` contains the names of the columns.
  `days <- names(Master)[which(names(Master) == "MON") + (0:6)]` is equivalent to
  `days <- c("MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN")`
- `data.table` requires consistent data types when parts of a column are updated. The day columns in `Master` are initialized to integer zero but `TimeDiff` in `Hours` is numeric. Therefore, the day columns in `Master` are coerced to double before updating.
- The `for` loop iterates over each day column and performs the *update join* for this column. For each match (`by = .EACHI`), the `Timediff` for the relevant day is picked.

In order to verify that `Master` has *not* been copied we can call

```
data.table::address(Master)
```

before and after the operation: The address of `Master` has not changed.

### Variant 2

This approach is a bit leaner. It also uses an *update join* but it is different to variant 1 as it reshapes (or pivots) `Hours` from long to wide format and removes the days columns from `Master` instead of coercing a bunch of integer zeroes to type numeric:

```
    library(data.table)
    days <- c("MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN")
    Hours_wide <- dcast(setDT(Hours)[, Day := ordered(Day, levels = days)], BranchNumber ~ Day)
    setDT(Master)[, (days) := NULL][
      Hours_wide, on = .(StoreNumber = BranchNumber), (days) := mget(paste0("i.", days))]
    Master[]
```

> ```
>    StoreNumber OtherCol MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN
> 1:           1        a 7.5   6 8.5   2   1 2.5  NA
> 2:           2        b  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 3:           3        c 7.5   6 8.5   2   1 2.5   5
> ```

Note that missing elements are now initialized to / indicated by `NA` which is much easier to detect, IMHO. If required, the `NA`s can be turned into another numeric value by

```
Master[, (days) := lapply(.SD, nafill, fill = 0), .SDcols = days][]
```

> ```
>    StoreNumber OtherCol MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN
> 1:           1        a 7.5   6 8.5   2   1 2.5   0
> 2:           2        b 0.0   0 0.0   0   0 0.0   0
> 3:           3        c 7.5   6 8.5   2   1 2.5   5
> ```

This approach uses `mget(paste0("i.", days))` to pick the days columns from `Hours`. If there are columns with the same name in both data.tables in a join, we can distinguish the columns by prepending the column names by a `x.` and `i.`, resp. Thus, `x.MON` refers to the `MON` column from the first data.table which is `Master` in  this case and `i.MON` refers to the `MON` column from the second data.table which is `Hours_wide`. `mget()` takes the column names as character strings and returns a list of the values of the respective columns.

### Variant 2 - Edit 1

Above code can be simplified by

```
setDT(Master)[, (days) := NULL][
  Hours_wide, on = .(StoreNumber = BranchNumber), (days) := mget(days)][]
```

> ```
>    StoreNumber OtherCol MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN
> 1:           1        a 7.5   6 8.5   2   1 2.5  NA
> 2:           2        b  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 3:           3        c 7.5   6 8.5   2   1 2.5   5
> ```

Because `setDT(Master)[, (days) := NULL]` already has removed the columns `MON` to `SUN` from `Master` there is no ambiguity on column names. Thus, the column names `MON` to `SUN` can be used without prepending them by `i.` as the only columns named `MON` to `SUN` are in `Hours_wide`.

### Variant 2 - Edit 2

With development version 1.14.1 as of 2021-05-10, a new interface for *programming on data.table* has been added (see [item 10 in NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#new-features) and the new vignette *programming on data.table*). Instead of `get()`/ `mget()` the new `env` argument is recommended:

```
library(data.table) # development version 1.14.1 used
days <- c("MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN")
Hours_wide <- dcast(setDT(Hours)[, Day := ordered(Day, levels = days)], BranchNumber ~ Day)
setDT(Master)[, (days) := NULL][
  Hours_wide, on = .(StoreNumber = BranchNumber), (days) := s,
  env = list(s = as.list(days))][]
```

> ```
>    StoreNumber OtherCol MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN
> 1:           1        a 7.5   6 8.5   2   1 2.5  NA
> 2:           2        b  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 3:           3        c 7.5   6 8.5   2   1 2.5   5
> ```

### Variant 3: `env` parameter and `fcoalesce()`

OP's expected result shows `0` instead of `NA`. With the *Variants 2* above, this was was achieved by a *separate update step* using `nafill()`.

This separate update step can be avoided by using the `fcoalesce()` function in the *update join*:

```
library(data.table) # development version 1.14.1 used
days <- c("MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN")
Hours_wide <- dcast(setDT(Hours)[, Day := ordered(Day, levels = days)], BranchNumber ~ Day)
setDT(Master)[, (days) := lapply(.SD, as.double), .SDcols = days][
  Hours_wide, on = .(StoreNumber = BranchNumber), (days) := lapply(s, fcoalesce, 0), 
  env = list(s = as.list(paste0("i.", days)))][]
```

> ```
>    StoreNumber OtherCol MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN
> 1:           1        a 7.5   6 8.5   2   1 2.5   0
> 2:           2        b 0.0   0 0.0   0   0 0.0   0
> 3:           3        c 7.5   6 8.5   2   1 2.5   5
> ```

### Data

```
library(data.table)

Master <- fread("
StoreNumber OtherCol MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN 
     1         a      0   0   0   0   0   0   0
     2         b      0   0   0   0   0   0   0
     3         c      0   0   0   0   0   0   0
", data.table = FALSE)
 
Hours <- fread("
BranchNumber   Day   TimeDiff
     1         MON   7.50
     1         TUE   6.00
     1         WED   8.50
     1         THU   2.00
     1         FRI   1.00
     1         SAT   2.50
     3         MON   7.50
     3         TUE   6.00
     3         WED   8.50
     3         THU   2.00
     3         FRI   1.00
     3         SAT   2.50
     3         SUN   5.00
", data.table = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Very well explained and both variants work perfectly fine...I do see how variant 2 is a much more efficient approach.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @GregorThomas comments, here is a longer then wider approach:

```
master <- data.frame(
  StoreNumber = 1:3,
  MON = 0,
  TUE = 0,
  WED = 0,
  THU = 0,
  FRI = 0,
  SAT = 0,
  SUN = 0
)

hours <- read.table(text = "BranchNumber   Day   TimeDiff
     1         MON   7.50
     1         TUE   6.00
     1         WED   8.50
     1         THU   2.00
     1         FRI   1.00
     1         SAT   2.50
     3         MON   7.50
     3         TUE   6.00
     3         WED   8.50
     3         THU   2.00
     3         FRI   1.00
     3         SAT   2.50
     3         SUN   5.00", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

master %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = MON:SUN,
    names_to = "Day",
    values_to = "Time"
  ) %>% 
  left_join(hours, by = c("StoreNumber" = "BranchNumber", "Day")) %>% 
  mutate(TimeDiff = replace_na(TimeDiff, 0),
         Time = TimeDiff) %>% 
  select(-TimeDiff) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = StoreNumber,
    names_from = Day,
    values_from = Time
  )
# A tibble: 3 x 8
  StoreNumber   MON   TUE   WED   THU   FRI   SAT   SUN
        <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1           1   7.5     6   8.5     2     1   2.5     0
2           2   0       0   0       0     0   0       0
3           3   7.5     6   8.5     2     1   2.5     5
```

---

## Edit

Here is a version where `master` has additional columns and the output is stored:

```
master <- data.frame(
  StoreNumber = 1:3,
  other_colum = c("A", "B", "C"),
  MON = 0,
  TUE = 0,
  WED = 0,
  THU = 0,
  FRI = 0,
  SAT = 0,
  SUN = 0
)

hours <- read.table(text = "BranchNumber   Day   TimeDiff
     1         MON   7.50
     1         TUE   6.00
     1         WED   8.50
     1         THU   2.00
     1         FRI   1.00
     1         SAT   2.50
     3         MON   7.50
     3         TUE   6.00
     3         WED   8.50
     3         THU   2.00
     3         FRI   1.00
     3         SAT   2.50
     3         SUN   5.00", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

master <- master %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = MON:SUN,
    names_to = "Day",
    values_to = "Time"
  ) %>% 
  left_join(hours, by = c("StoreNumber" = "BranchNumber", "Day")) %>% 
  mutate(TimeDiff = replace_na(TimeDiff, 0),
         Time = TimeDiff) %>% 
  select(-TimeDiff) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Day,
    values_from = Time
  )

master
# A tibble: 3 x 9
  StoreNumber other_colum   MON   TUE   WED   THU   FRI   SAT   SUN
        <int> <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1           1 A             7.5     6   8.5     2     1   2.5     0
2           2 B             0       0   0       0     0   0       0
3           3 C             7.5     6   8.5     2     1   2.5     5
```

Comment: This is great! things seem to have matched up nicely. But rather than have the output result show in the console as a tibble table, how would you go about attaching the results to the 'Master' Table as individual columns (Mon-Sun), whilst ensuring they still correspond to the StoreNumber...So the idea being at the end of the Master table there will a column for each week day with the data populated

Comment: The printing was just to show that it works, I now store the result first. Also, I've changed `pivot_wider` a bit so that `master` can include other columns. Does this work for you?

Comment: That works now - it is joining onto the Master Table! However I am still getting the duplicating issue...in the Master table each line item is duplicating...the 1st row fills in from MON:SAT then SUN is on the next duplicated line...sometimes the rows triples and quadruples , so if duplicating 4x then Mon to Wed filled on the normal line then the next line is Thu and Fri filled then the next is Sat and the next is Sun 0

Comment: ok to tackle this I would need more example data that shows this behaviour